# Paypal Payment Data Transfer in Sandbox not Redirecting Correctly

Tags: php, redirect, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I implemented a chained payment which is working perfectly well in the sandbox. However, I wanted to use **Payment Data Transfer** https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/payment-data-transfer/ instead of **IPN** since the user should be redirected directly and see the status of his payment. **IPN** is working fine, however, the redirect url is called without the needed parameter.

I've done the following to activate **PDT**

- activated automated redirect
- set my redirect url
- activated payment data transfer

The credentials I use are maintained in the developer area > sandbox accounts

For my payment I have to pass a redirect url as parameter since it cannot be null. This is the url which is called after my payment. However, it's **not** called directly **and** it's missing the parameter for the payment key.

Answer (score 0):

Found the "solution" : Payment Data Transfer is not working with chained payments.